# Un/Subscribe to events in Xamarin Content View

Tags: xamarin.forms, mvvmcross

I have a `TabView` inside of my `ContentPage` and to keep things clean I usually put my tabs in a `ContentView`

My `ContentView` in this example has a few Entry controls. I want to subscribe to the `TextChanged` event for the control so I can display a character counter label on the page.

Now I'm not sure if this is correct or not but I keep these UI functions in the code behind as to my knowledge they have no place in the VM.

The issue is; in the `ContentPage` there is no way to get a reference to the control when its buried in a `ContentView` and if I try to move the logic to the `ContentView` there is no access to the usual `OnAppearing` & `OnDisappearing` methods. I'm using MVVMCross and at the moment I'm subscribing to the event in the `OnBindingContextChanged` method. However, I cant see anything that gets triggered when the page is closed / popped.

Comment: do you mean OnAppearing, those arent available in ContentViews?

Comment: Yes that's correct and that's part of the issue.

Comment: ContentViews don't have a lifecycle, you would need to do a workaround. if you explain a little more what exactly is the requirements maybe I can help

Comment: Let me know what's not clear from the post and I'll edit it to make it clearer. It seems to make sense to me.

Comment: What is the need to subscribe for events in your `ContentView`s? Could you achieve the behavior you want simply by binding to the View Model or by implementing a Behavior or Attached Property?

Comment: Basically I want way to update a label on the same page as the entry, so when the user types the label updates. "2 / 50 characters", something like that.

Comment: I was thinking maybe this can be better achieved by using a trigger in the XAML ?

Answer (score 0):

I was over thinking this as usual.

What I was wanting to achieve was to simply update a `Label` when the text in an `Entry` changed. I keep my UI specific code in the XAML and code behind but I was having issues in un/subscribing to the `TextChanged` events in the code behind.

I don't know why I don't think of this before; just wire the `TextChanged` event in the XAML instead of doing it in the code behind and that way the unsubscribe is already taken care of.

Comment: I'm not sure if Binding was the correct way forwards here. I try to keep the VM out of the equation if its just pure UI stuff.